# Updating table in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, sql-update

I have a table in Oracle call STATISTICS.

```
COLUMN NAME     DATE TYPE
```

---

```
MODEL           VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)       
NEW_COUNT       NUMBER      
NEW_DATE        DATE        
OLD_COUNT       NUMBER      
OLD_DATE        DATE        
PRNCT_CHANGE    NUMBER
```

Now I have sql that updates statistics table:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS
SET
    OLD_COUNT = NEW_COUNT,
    NEW_COUNT =
    ( -- semantic table --
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM TABLE(SEM_MATCH(
        '{
              ?s ?p ?o
         }',
        SEM_Models(MODEL),NULL,
        SEM_ALIASES(SEM_ALIAS('','http://SEMANTIC#')),NULL))
    ),
    OLD_DATE = NEW_DATE,
    NEW_DATE = SYSDATE

WHERE MODEL = &MY_MODEL    
;
```

Now, can I do this? Push the date from a new date to an old date before I update the new date?
I am also doing the same thing with the NEW_COUNT and OLD_COUNT...

It sounded logical but is ok to do this?

Comment: Did you try running it?  Yes, it should work.

Comment: I just tried it. It worked.Thanks @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

So I followed my own advice :) and it worked just fine. I am not sure if this is the best practice but it does the trick